# Imagebutton is not visible in Oncreate and not clickable

Tags: android, android-layout, visibility, imagebutton

I just want to add a onClick method in my Imagebutton, but the imagebutton is just not visible, but in my layout. My button somehow was visible, but my onclick method didn't work. For some reason the imagebutton is visible in my layout, but again not when I start my application.

*MainActivity.java*

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome to Basic IPTV !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




       isPreparing = false;
       pauseisclicked = true;
       imgbuttonisclicked = false;
        isUp = false;
        IsDisabled = false;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1001);
        }






        //For now we just picked an arbitrary item to play


        imgbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mainlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainlistview);
        noresults = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noresults);

        noresults.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        imgbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



        imgbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new MaterialFilePicker()
                        .withActivity(MainActivity.this)
                        .withRequestCode(1000)
                        .withFilter(Pattern.compile(".*\\.m3u$")) // Filtering files and directories by file name using regexp

                        .withHiddenFiles(true) // Show hidden files and folders
                        .start();
            }


        });


    }
```

layout, but text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="102dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="319dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/noresults"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout4"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="338dp"
        android:layout_height="99dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="176dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="First, add a m3u playlist from your M3U-Subscribtion by clicking the button below or click on the three dots and then on open m3u..."
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/mainlistview"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.723"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/mainlistview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mainlistview" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainlistview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="2dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout4">

    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noresults"
        android:layout_width="248dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="No channel found"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/mainlistview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mainlistview" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="278dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageButton7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

This is my layout:

[image: layout]

Here: A screenshot of my device (it's real)
[image: my device]

Comment: Your layout is so weird, the problem could be related to the dimension of your phone, because the Views position seem to be set in an absolute way, and not constrained, as it'd be in a ConstraintLayout. So, there's a reason why, for example, you don't constraint your button to be centered horizontally and vertically below the textView?

Comment: try giving the imagebutton fixed height and a background color black to see where it actually exists in the view , and as Luca said you need to confirm that the constraints are correct and the item is not hanging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your imagebutton xml:

```
   <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="102dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="319dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout4"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have very big `android:layout_marginBottom="319dp"`. If you run the app on the smaller device, your `imageButton` might be positioned outside of the screen.

Overall, your layout's code looks like it could be improved. If you are new to Android app development, I suggest you to use `LinearLayout` because they're simpler to use. Or watch some tutorials about `ConstraintLayout` and how to use it.

Comment: Ok I think I'm going to use a LinearLayout.